# Jenkins httprequest multipart form POST

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to use the [Jenkins httprequest](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/http_request/) plugin to do a multipart FORM POST.
The multipart POST must consist of two parts:

- form-data name="model" with JSON
- form-data name="sourcePath" which is a file

I cannot figure out in the documentation how to create a multipart form.

I can set 1 `multipartName`, `requestBody`, `uploadFile` parameter, not multiple.

Does anyone know how to build a multipart FORM request? Is it possible?